# Remove characters from Array values

Tags: php, arrays

Thanks guys.

I've been towing over this one for over a day now and it's just too difficult for me! I'm trying to remove the last 3 characters from each value within an array. Currently, I've tried converting to a string, then doing the action, then moving into a new array... can't get anything to work. Someone suggested this, but it doesn't work. I need an array of postcodes, "EC1 2AY, EC3 4XW..." converting to "EC1, EC3, ..." and it be back in an Array!!

```
implode(" ",array_map(function($v){ return ucwords(substr($v, 0, -3)); }, 
array_keys($area_elements)));
```

This hasn't worked, and obviously when I converted to a string and do a trim function, it will only take the last 3 characters from the last "variable" in the string.

Please send HELP!

Comment: Apologies - I've already converted to string to remove the spaces in-between the postcodes, then converted back to an Array, so its "EC12AY, EC34XW, ..." etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an array back, you shouldn't `implode`. You are almost there:

```
$area_elements = ['EC1 2AY', 'EC3 4XW'];

$result = array_map(function($v){ 
  return trim(substr($v, 0, -3)); 
}, $area_elements);

var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "EC1"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "EC3"
}
```

Comment: Okay, so $result is the defined, new Array?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:
`altering array by reference`.

Snippet

```
$area_elements = ['EC1 2AY', 'EC3 4XW'];

foreach($area_elements as &$v){ 
  $v = substr($v, 0, -4); 
}

print_r($area_elements);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => EC1
    [1] => EC3
)
```

Live [demo](https://3v4l.org/C20vN)

[Pass by reference docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)